# Set view plugin submit handler

Tags: views, 8, plugins

I'm trying to create my own AreaPlugin. But there's submit handler doesn't work.

Here is a part of my code.

```
class MyAreaPlugin extends AreaPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render($empty = FALSE) {
    $result['my_plugin_form'] = [
      '#type' => 'form',
      '#form_id' => 'my_plugin_form_id',
    ];
    $result['my_plugin_form']['actions'] = ['#type' => 'actions'];
    // There will be more actions.
    $result['my_plugin_form']['actions']['button_id'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Button text',
      '#name' => 'button_name',
      '#submit' => [[$this, 'buttonClickHandler']],
    ];
    return $result;
  }

  /**
   * Button click handler.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   This form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   This form state.
   */
  public function buttonClickHandler(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('exportData');
  }
}
```

How it can be done correct way?

Comment: What is in AreaPluginBase? How do you render the form?

Comment: It is @ingroup views_area_handlers. And AreaPluginBase is core abstract class.
I simple create view with filters and sotring and add this plugin in header area.

Comment: I mean Drupal\views\Plugin\views\area\AreaPluginBase core class.

Comment: I see, then you have to put the form in a form class (extending FormBase) and build the form in render(): `$result['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm')`

Comment: I don't need to have a form. All information which I need, I have in MyPlugin class. Is there any possibility to handle submit right here without additional useless classes?

Comment: render() is for the content you want to display in a view area. You can in theory display there anything, also a form like in my last comment. But if you want to do something different, can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to start batch on submit. Batch with result of view. It is reason to keep this code in this class.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question, how to get the result of a view in a batch. Seems to be more like you need a DisplayPlugin.

Comment: I am not so sure. I need to know why submit action not handle. Another question - "How to start batch from DisplayPlugin? (without parameters, because I know how to have result)" is for another post.

Comment: Submit handlers only work in a form. If you want to put some kind of an action in render(), then use a normal link to an export display of the view or to a batch which uses an embedded view.

Comment: The last comment is the answer which I really want to know. Thanks. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Submit handlers only work in a form. If you want to put some kind of an action in render(), then use a normal link to an export display of the view or to a batch which uses an embedded view.